# Calling a bean method from another method annotated as Bean

Tags: java, spring

I have two methods annotated with @Bean. I am calling one @Bean annotated method from another. Does it mean it creates two beans of the same type?

Here's my code:

```
@Configuration
@Import({BaseConfig.class})
public class TestConfig{

    @Autowired
    BaseConfig baseconfig;
    @Bean
    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public SampleTestClass sampleTest() {
        return new SampleTestClass(baseconfig.createNewBean());
    }

}

@Configuration
@Import(SomeClassConfig.class)
public class BaseConfig {

    @Autowired
    private int someAttribute;

    @Bean
    public SampleTest createNewBean() {
        return new SampleTest(someAttribute);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it wouldn't.

`SampleTest` has a `singleton` scope which is the default, so even if you call the method "directly", Spring will make sure that there is only one instance per container.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't. Spring automatically proxies `@Configuration` classes at runtime and decorates `@Bean` methods to provide the correct scope behavior.

However, in your case it would be cleaner not to tangle the two configurations unnecessarily. Instead, you could do this:

```
@Bean
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public SampleTestClass sampleTest(SampleTest dependency) {
    return new SampleTestClass(dependency);
}
```